How can a light ray have two different phase velocities?
In "Classical Theory of Electricity and Magnetism" by A. K. Raychaudhuri I found the following text regarding EM waves in anisotropic media (see p. 153):
$$ "\frac{n_1^2}{v^2-c_1^2} + \frac{n_2^2}{v^2-c_2^2} + \frac{n_2^2}{v^2-c_2^2} = 0 \tag{13.14} $$
Equation (13.14) is a quadratic in $v^2$ and shows that for any $\vec{n}$ (i.e., the direction of wave normal), the phase velocity has two distinct values."
I don't quite understand what this means. Thinking of it as EM plane wave modes, how can on of these have two different phase velocities? Does the birefringence create a new set of modes which are now pairs of copropagating plane waves at different velocities?

Electromagnetic waves in media are collective excitations. Not only do we have the free electromagnetic field, but we also have to deal with the local polarization of the material.  The effective field is the superposition of both. The additional degrees of freedom that are necessary to have a second phase velocity are being supplied by the optical material. Is that what you are asking?

@FlatterMann Yes, but more general. For example, how would this look like written out, for example as the fourier exapansion in terms of plane waves? Are there additional terms due to the possibility of an additional velocity? Basically, do we now have more plane wave modes?

For each ${\bf n}$ there are two directions of the $E$ field that have well defined veclocities,

The additional terms come from the relative orientation of the crystallographic axes of the medium to the k-vector of the light. You can look up the relevant forms of Maxwell's equations for anisotropic media on the internet or in the textbooks. I am not a theorist and I am not going to write those out just for the fun of it. Mike Stone is right. You get two effective speeds of light for the collective excitation, even for the most simple case of isotropic media. For anisotropic media it gets even worse.

@mikestone Do these coincide with the two polarization directions? Or are the two for each polarization direction?

They are the two polarizations.

@mikestone Thak you for the clarification. They way it was written int the book, without the mention of polarization at all, this sounded like there were two independent velocities for the same polarization. Of course there would then be no criterion to decide which one it its for a given beam, which does not make sense physically.
